# Can somebody simplify the below code struct {int a[2];} arr[] = {{1},{2}};?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
struct {int a[2];} arr[] = {{1},{2}};
```

Please simplify the above code specially the `arr[] = {{1},{2}};` part and how it's related to the structure.

---

p.s.:- `arr[] = {{1},{2}}` the initialization seems to be of a `2d array` but the lvalue assignment is done to `1d array(arr[])`. Again what will `a[2]` hold if we call `arr[].a[2]`.

Comment: Simplify how ? What is your question exactly ? `arr`is an array of 2 elements, each element being a structure composed of an array of 2 `int` called  `a`

Comment: I guess it is some kind of howework since I don't understand the benefit of such a structure declaration (or may be some kind of trick that the C langage allows). But anyway I think the initialisation of the structure elements is not complete: `arr[0][1]` is not initialised (tried on onlinegdb)

Comment: arr[] = {{1},{2}} the initialization seems to be of a 2d array but the lvalue assignment is done to 1d array. Again what will a[2] hold if we call arr[].a[2].

Comment: "... if we call arr[].a[2]" >>> you cannot use arr[].a[2]; the 'internal' array indices are `0` and `1`

Comment: "What will a[2] hold" means that you have yet to grasp how arrays work. So start with declaring a plain integer array, initialize it and print its contents. Once you have studied that, you can move on to structs.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct {int a[2];} arr[] = {{1},{2}};
```

The above initialization as of now is incomplete and you should see the below warning

```
warning: (near initialization for ‘arr[0].a’)
```

The proper initialization is

```
struct {int a[2];} arr[] = {{{1}},{{2}}};
```

---

```
1.

   { { {1} },{ {2} }}
       ---
        |
         --------------> is for int arr[0].a[0] // in this case arr[0].a[1] will be not be initialized

2 

   { { {1} } , { {2} }} 
     -------   ------ 
        |        |
        |         ----> is for arr[1]
        --------------> is for arr[0]

3
   { { {1} } , { {2} }} 
   --------------------
             |
              ------------------> is for complete arr[]
```

Comment: what is the need of triple curly braces?

Comment: @wupiku I have already explained as part of the answer see the examples.

Comment: There is no "partial initialization" in C. Everything is initialized. In the absence of a definite initializer, `0` (of the right kind) will be used.

Comment: @wupiku You have an array (needs one brace level) of structs (needs one brace level) with a single element that is an array (needs one brace level), therefore three levels of braces in total.

Comment: @pmg I'm not sure it would be the case for a local variable.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: local variables (as any other variable) are either uninitialized or fully initialized. `int local[7] = {1, 2}; /* local[6] **is** 0 */`

Comment: Really ? I didn't know that.

Comment: The original definition doesn't report any errors with clang even with `-Wall`. It *seems* to be as if you used `{ { { 1, 0 } }, { { 2, 0 } } }` but accessing the second element of each `a` might be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JeremyP: there is no "partial initialization" in C.

Answer (score 0):

> simplify `struct {int a[2];} arr[] = {{1},{2}};`

```
struct quux {
    int a[2];
};

struct quux arr[2];
arr[0].a[0] = 1;
arr[0].a[1] = 0;
arr[1].a[0] = 2;
arr[1].a[1] = 0;
```

Comment: In mu opinion it is a better answer than playing with curly braces. Clear, easy to read, no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's get a grip on the rules for aggregate (array or struct) initialization. The [C17 standard draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) says in  6.7.9, Initialization:

> <sup>17</sup> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated *current object.* When no designations are present, **subobjects** of the current object are initialized in order [...].

So a list of initializers **also initializes subobjects** (even without inner braces).

The *current object* inside the outermost brace pair is `arr`, the array of structures. The *current object* inside the inner brace pairs are the elements of the array, `arr[i]`. There are two sub-initializer lists in the intializer list for `arr`, giving `arr`  an element count of 2.

The inner initializer lists `{1}`  resp. `{2}` are used to each initialize a single one of the unnamed structures. Each structure `arr[i]` in turn contains an aggregate, namely the member array `a`, so that the following rule is important:

> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates[...], **these rules apply recursively** to the subaggregates [...].

The initializer list for the struct in `arr[0]` is `{1}`, so the lone element `1`  is used to initialize its elements. The only element is `a`, an array of 2 ints. Because of the recursive rule the 1 is used to initialize this sub-aggregate, each element in order. Because there is only one initializer for all of `arr[0], the second int element in`a` has no matching initializer. Here the following rule comes into play:

> <sup>19</sup>  [...]  All subobjects that are not initialized explicitly **shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

Static objects are zero-initialized (6.7.9/10).

The same reasoning applies to the second element in `arr`.

This way we end up with an `arr` that has two elements, each one an unnamed struct that contains an array of 2 int, of which the first one is initialized with the given value, and the second one implicitly with zero.

Let's play a little with these rules. For example, we can *provide no initializers* which zero-initializes all members/elements of automatic variables. (How often have I seen people memset in these cases!)

```
    struct jumble { int i; char *p; float f; };
    void f() { struct jumble arr[10] = {}; /* zero numbers, nullpointer */ }
```

Building from your example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct int2T { int a[2]; };

void printStructArr(const char *name, struct int2T *arr, size_t numElems)
{
    for(int arri=0; arri<numElems; arri++)
    {
        for(int ai=0; ai < sizeof(arr[arri].a)/sizeof(*arr[arri].a); ai++)
        {   fputs(name, stdout);
            printf("[%d].a[%d]: %d\n", arri, ai, arr[arri].a[ai]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct int2T arr1[] = {{1},{2}};
    // equivalent: Proper bracing
    struct int2T arr1b[] = { // arr                    array of structs               
                              { // arr[0]              single struct
                                 { // arr[0].a         member array within struct
                                    1, // arr[0].a[0]  int
                                    0  // arr[0].a[1]  int
                                 }
                              },
                              { // arr[1]              single struct
                                 { // arr[1].a         member array within struct
                                    2, // arr[1].a[0]  int
                                    0  // arr[1].a[1]  int
                                 }
                              }
    };

    struct int2T arr2[] = { // arr, array of structs
                            11, // trying to initialize arr[0] 
                                   // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[0].a
                                        // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[0].a[0]. Success!

                            12 }; // same as above.
    struct int2T arr3[] = { 
                            21, // trying to initialize arr[0] 
                                   // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[0].a
                                        // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[0].a[0]. Success!
                            22,         //  next element in array, initialize arr[0].a[1]. Success!
                            23          // elements in inner array "a" exhausted, unwind recursion
                                   // trying to continue initializing arr[0]. No more members to initialize, 
                                   // unwinding recursion to next upper level.
                                // trying to initialize next element in array "arr", arr[1] 
                                    // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[1].a
                                        // -> recursing: trying to initialize arr[1].a[0]. Success!
                                        // no more initializer left for arr[1].a[1] 
                                        // -> Zero-initialize arr[1].a[1], then unwind.
                                    // Continuing initialization of arr[1]: No more members, unwind
                                // Continuing initialization of arr: No more initializers left, stop.
                          };


    printStructArr("arr1", arr1, sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(*arr1));
    printStructArr("arr1b", arr1b, sizeof(arr1b)/sizeof(*arr1b));
    printStructArr("arr2", arr2, sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(*arr2));
    printStructArr("arr3", arr3, sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(*arr3));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
arr1[0].a[0]: 1
arr1[0].a[1]: 0
arr1[1].a[0]: 2
arr1[1].a[1]: 0

arr1b[0].a[0]: 1
arr1b[0].a[1]: 0
arr1b[1].a[0]: 2
arr1b[1].a[1]: 0

arr2[0].a[0]: 11
arr2[0].a[1]: 12

arr3[0].a[0]: 21
arr3[0].a[1]: 22
arr3[1].a[0]: 23
arr3[1].a[1]: 0
```